# Find values in array of hashes to create new array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have some data returned from an api which I've parsed down to this:

```
[{:a=>value1, :b=>value2, :c=>value3, :d=>value4}, {:a=>value5, :b=>value6, :c=>value7, :d=>value8},{:a=>value9, :b=>value10, :c=>value11, :d=>value12}, ...]
```

How can I create a new array of hashes with the **keys AND values** of `b` and `c`, given `key = b` and `key = c`?  I want to pass the key and return the value and maintain the key. So I want to end up with:

```
[{:b=>value2, :c=>value3}, {:b=>value6, :c=>value7}, {:b=>value10, :c=>value11}, ...]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Pure ruby

```
array = [{:a=>'value1', :b=>'value2', :c=>'value3', :d=>'value4'}, {:a=>'value1', :b=>'value2', :c=>'value3', :d=>'value4'}]

b_and_c_array = array.map{|a| a.select{|k, _| [:b, :c].include?(k)} }
```

We take each hash using the `map` method that will return a result array. For each hash, we select only `[:b, :c]` keys. You can add more inside it.

#### Rails

If using Rails, let's use `Hash#slice`, prettier :

```
b_and_c_array = array.map{|a| a.slice(:b, :c) }
```

Comment: Wow! Worked like a charm. I'm trying to get lat and lng info from api data into json for google maps api rendering. This method lets me select the lat and lng values as [{lat=>value1, lng=>value2},...] but I need [{lat:value1, lng:value2}]. Any idea about this? Appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean? The api sends you malformed json back?

Comment: I got it. Just needed to convert results to_json. Thanks!